# Unity setting a dark screen effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am creating scene with the night effect. I want night to be more darker.

For this I used ambient light and set its ambient color to 0( for RGB) which should show the darkness in the scene but this only brings some amount of darkness which makes object very clearly visible which I don't want. Is there any way to make the scene more dark? My game is a 2D game.

This image should be more darker.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the scene to be clickable? Or are you using keyboard controls?

Comment: yes scene is clickable. I am using keyboard to move the character and mouse click to collect the item like wood.

Comment: Window>Lighting>Settings>intesity multiplier try to lower it

Comment: I tried that but I need to set it  at runtime how can I change that at runtime. Currently setting ambient color at run time with this
RenderSettings.ambientLight = new Color(40 / 255f, 40 / 255f, 40 / 255f, 0);

Comment: Don't control the dark, control the light. Make it dark in settings, and then add lighting which you will control in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Switch off any light which may be in the scene.

```
Light[] ligths = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Light)) as Light[];
    foreach (Light ligth in ligths) {
        ligth.enabled = false;
}
```

And later set the ambientLight to be black.

```
RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.black;
```

With this the scene will be completely in darkness, so you will need to add some light later to see the map.